# Display Tumblr blog in Wordpress but only for a certain category

Tags: php

All,
I have a wordpress blog but I have a client that uses Tumblr for their blogs. I know that there are Wordpress plugins out there that import the Tumblr blogs into Wordpress but I don't want to do that. I'd like it to just go out and pull the Tumblr blogs for a category of "News" for example and then display them as Wordpress blog posts.

Has anyone ever done anything like this? Does anyone have an ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found PHPTumblr which does everything I need:

https://code.google.com/p/phptumblr/